# Does Ace have a mode for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ace-editor

I've just embedded [ace](http://ajaxorg.github.io/ace/#nav=about) on my website; does it have a mode for MySQL?

I see SQL, but nothing specific for MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

For now there are only sql and postegres sql modes.
Adding a new mode for MySQL should be relatively easy, i'd suggest to open an issue on github about this.

Comment: [opened](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1373); also, temporarily [rolled my own](https://gist.github.com/mnbayazit/5392826) based on postgres, with different keywords and functions.